# no record saved in DB in Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android application I save record in DB each time some action is done. The code is below:

```
    Cursor histCurr = db.rawQuery("select * from HistStore order by seqNum", null);
    Log.d("DBHIST", histCurr.getCount() +" rows in DB0.");
    db.beginTransaction();
    long ret = db.insert("HistStore", null, newValues);
    db.endTransaction();
    if(ret<0){
        Log.d("DBHIST", "\r\n!!! Error to save history into DB!!!\r\n");
    }else{
        Log.d("DBHIST", ret+" rows inserted.");
        histCurr = db.rawQuery("select * from HistStore order by seqNum", null);
        Log.d("DBHIST", histCurr.getCount() +" rows in DB1.");
    }
```

The log is:

DBHIST(918): 30 rows in DB0.

DBHIST(918): 31 rows inserted.

DBHIST(918): 30 rows in DB1.

I expect to get 31 rows in last print. Why I do not get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you started a transaction, you need to mark it as successful for the changes to persist!

Try doing this:

```
Cursor histCurr = db.rawQuery("select * from HistStore order by seqNum", null);
Log.d("DBHIST", histCurr.getCount() +" rows in DB0.");
db.beginTransaction();
long ret = -1;
try{
    ret = db.insert("HistStore", null, newValues);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
catch(Exception e){

}
finally{
    db.endTransaction();
}

if(ret<0){
    Log.d("DBHIST", "\r\n!!! Error to save history into DB!!!\r\n");
}else{
    Log.d("DBHIST", ret+" rows inserted.");
    histCurr = db.rawQuery("select * from HistStore order by seqNum", null);
    Log.d("DBHIST", histCurr.getCount() +" rows in DB1.");
}
```

Comment: Also, OP is incorrect in semantics. Variable `ret` holds an id of the successfully inserted row. So the expression `Log.d("DBHIST", ret+" rows inserted.")` is incorrect semantically, it should sound like `"row with id=" + ret + " inserted"`.

Comment: True, knowing the value of ret as long as it is >=0 is not very helpful. He does seem to be querying the db and checking it's count after that though